# Angular smooth infinite scrolling of appending text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

just need some help with Angular and Animation. I want to scroll some text which is expanded dynamically line by line in an area from bottom to top with a smooth animation.

I found some css animation code, which does this. Here a plunkr: [css animation](http://plnkr.co/edit/IbnJSFnPykKBPp0ZPGJb)

I made some demo of the Angular App. In the app there is some text area and after clicking start Button some sample text is appended every 500ms.

I added the ScrollGlue Directive on the text area which automaically scrolls the text to the bottom line.

Made some demo in plunkr: [demoscroll](http://plnkr.co/edit/mUODxlJKKgkNhXFIQEWh)

So the question is, how can i add some smooth scrolling to the text as in the plunkr above?

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {ScrollGlueDirective} from './scrollGlue.directive';

@NgModule({    
  declarations: [
    DemoScrollComponent,
    ScrollGlueDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,

  ],
  providers: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [DemoScrollComponent,]
})


export class AppModule { }
```

**demoscroll.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{line}}
      <div class="demo-scroll-area" scrollGlue>
        <ul>
          <li *ngFor="let item of content">
            <p>{{ item }}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button (click)="startTextScroll()">Start</button>
      <button (click)="stopTextScroll()">Stop</button>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`.demo-scroll-area {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  li {
    list-style-type: none;
  }

  li:hover {
    background: rgb(182, 150, 136);
  }
  `]
})
export class DemoScrollComponent {
  content: any = [];
  line: string = 'Aliquam consequatur dolore earum et eum in';
  lineCounter: number = 0;

  interval: any;

  constructor() {

  }

  startTextScroll() {
    console.log('startTextScroll()');

    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.addTextLine();
    }, 500);
  }

  stopTextScroll() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);

  }

  addTextLine() {
    this.content.push(this.lineCounter + ' ' + this.line)
    this.lineCounter++;
  }

}
```

**scrollGlue.directive.ts**

```
import {AfterContentInit, Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input} from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollGlue]'
})

export class ScrollGlueDirective  implements AfterContentInit {
  public el: any;
  public isLocked: boolean = false;
  private _observer: any;
  private _oldScrollHeight: number = 0;

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = _el.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.el.scrollTop = this.el.scrollHeight;

    // create an observer instance
    this._observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      if ( !this.isLocked ) {
        this._oldScrollHeight = this.el.scrollHeight;
        this.el.scrollTop = this.el.scrollHeight;
      }
    });

    // configuration of the observer:
    let config = { childList: true, subtree: true };
    let target = this.el;

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    this._observer.observe(target, config);
  }

  @HostListener('scroll') onScroll() {
    this.el.scrollTop = this.el.scrollHeight;

    // let percent = (this.el.scrollHeight / 100);
    // console.log('percent', percent)
    // if (this.el.scrollHeight - this.el.scrollTop > (10 * percent)) {
    //   this.isLocked = true;
    // } else {
    //   this.isLocked = false;
    // }
  }

  OnDestroy() {
    this._observer.disconnect();
  }
}
```